# I'm not getting the no of parameters concept in CNN

Tags: cnn, convolution

[image][image]

Hi guys i've attached two images of question please help me on solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [detailed answer on Medium](https://medium.com/@iamvarman/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-in-the-cnn-5bd55364d7ca).